# How to detect circles in still image using Swift?

Tags: swift, machine-learning, geometry, object-recognition

I am aware of [CIRectangleFeature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cirectanglefeature), but I have no idea how to recognize circles.

I would appreciate if anyone experienced point me to right direction. I am also aware of openCV framework but reluctant to use it due to its library size.

Is there a way to achieve this through Machine Learning? Having images of what we are looking for in the application?